# Every differentiable function is also Lebesgue measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.
Explain why $f $ is Lebesgue measurable.

I have no clue how to start.
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: $f$ is continuous, so if $a \in \mathbb R$ then $f^{-1}((-\infty, a))$ is open. And we know that open sets are Lebesgue measurable. So $f^{-1}((-\infty, a))$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is differentiable then $f$ is  continuous. Hence it is Borel measurable. Borel measurable functions are also Lebesgue measurable.